# Add class only executes on last div in arrray

Tags: javascript

When the top property of each div `.js-player` is between 10 and 100 the word `#mute`should have the class `.active` added. The code below only executes the adding of `.active` on the last `.js-active` div. Where am I going wrong? Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-player')),
          mute = document.querySelector('#mute');
        
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        players.forEach(function(player) {
            let distance = player.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            
            if (10 < distance && distance < 100) {
                mute.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                mute.classList.remove('active');
            }
        })
    });
```

```css
.js-player {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 8em 2em;
}

#mute {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}


.filler {
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>

<div class="filler"></div>

<div id="mute">mute</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, you say it only adds the active class to the last div.  The last div is the only one I see with the `id="mute"` tag so of course it only adds it to the last div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you are wondering is why only the last `.js-player` determines whether or not the div has the `active` class?

If so, each time a scroll event happens, it loops over the players, and either add or removes the `active` class.  So, when it gets to the last `.js-player`, if this last `.js-player` is not within the distance, it will remove the `active` class if another one set it, and add it if is, it will set it even if another one removed it.

What you need to do is stop checking once you have found a player within the distance required, something like:

```js
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-player')),
          mute = document.querySelector('#mute');
        
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
        var matched = false;
        players.forEach(function(player) {
            if (matched) return;
            let distance = player.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            
            if (10 < distance && distance < 100) {
                mute.classList.add('active');
                matched = true;
            } else {
                mute.classList.remove('active');
            }
        })
    });
```

```css
.js-player {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 8em 2em;
}

#mute {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}


.filler {
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>

<div class="filler"></div>

<div id="mute">mute</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It makes a lot sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `active` class on mute element on each iteration, which means that only the last element of array will matter.

Here's a working verions:

```js
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-player'));
const mute = document.querySelector('#mute');
        
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var active = false;
    players.forEach(function (player) {
        let distance = player.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            
        if (10 < distance && distance < 100) {
            active = true;
        }
    });
        
    active ? mute.classList.add('active') : mute.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
.js-player {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 8em 2em;
}

#mute {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}


.filler {
 height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>
<div class="js-player"></div>

<div class="filler"></div>

<div id="mute">mute</div>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply with a succinct solution. I understand what I was doing wrong now